# Решить задачу «Электронные часы» __одной командой__

Tags: любой-язык, соревнование

[Условие](http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/inout_and_arithmetic_operations/problems/electronic_watch/)

Дано число n. С начала суток прошло n минут. Определите, сколько часов и минут будут показывать электронные часы в этот момент. Программа должна вывести два числа: количество часов (от 0 до 23) и количество минут (от 0 до 59). Учтите, что число n может быть больше, чем количество минут в сутках.

Суть соревнования в том, чтобы решить эту задачу **без использования точки с запятой (или других разделителей команд)**

Примеры ввода и соответствующего вывода (результат):

```
In [38]: [print('%s:    %s %s'%(x, *divmod(x%1440,60)))
    ...:  for x in [3, 150, 1441, 444, 180, 1439, 1440, 2000, 3456, 5678, 9876]]
    ...:
3:      0 3
150:    2 30
1441:   0 1
444:    7 24
180:    3 0
1439:   23 59
1440:   0 0
2000:   9 20
3456:   9 36
5678:   22 38
9876:   20 36
```

PS `lambda` функциями пользоваться можно!

PPS задача изначально задумана для решения на Python, поэтому не обессудьте...

Для составления таблицы просьба правильно оформлять заголовок ответа.

**Таблица лидеров:**

```js
execute("ru.stackoverflow.com", "620564");
```

```css
.cssload-container,.cssload-cube{width:97px;height:97px;transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container,.cssload-cube,.cssload-half1,.cssload-half2{transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container{position:relative;margin:23px 84px;perspective:292px}.cssload-cube{animation:cube 11.5s forwards infinite;transform-origin:center 49px}.cssload-half1,.cssload-s1{top:0;transform-origin:50% 100%}.cssload-half1{height:39px;position:absolute;animation:half-fold 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-side{width:19px;height:19px;background:#ddd;position:absolute}.cssload-s1{left:39px;animation:s1ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s2,.cssload-s3,.cssload-s4{left:39px;transform-origin:50% 0}.cssload-s2{top:19px;animation:s2ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s3{top:39px;animation:s3ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s4{top:58px;animation:s4ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s5{left:19px;top:19px;transform-origin:100% 50%;animation:s5ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s6{left:58px;top:39px;transform-origin:0 50%;animation:s6ani 11.5s forwards infinite}@keyframes cube{0%,30%{transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}60%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}65%,70%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(180deg)}75%,80%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(1turn)}90%{transform:rotateX(0) rotate(0) rotate(0)}}@keyframes s1ani{0%{opacity:1;transform:translateY(0);background:#ddd}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(-90deg);background:#ddd}90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@keyframes s2ani{0%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%,80%{background:#b4b4b4}65%{opacity:1;background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s3ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}20%,90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%{background:#969696}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s4ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%,to{opacity:0}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(90deg);background:#b4b4b4}80%{background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(90deg)}}@keyframes s5ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(-179deg)}20%{opacity:1;background:#ddd;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(90deg)}55%{background:#ddd}60%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{transform:rotateY(90deg);opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s6ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(179deg)}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(-90deg);background:#ddd}60%,80%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(-90deg)}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes half-fold{0%,50%{transform:rotateX(0)}60%,90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://mayorovp.github.io/codegolf/table-8c505e68f1349e4c69e7.js"></script>
<div class=cssload-container><div class=cssload-cube><div class=cssload-half1><div class="cssload-side cssload-s1"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s2"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s5"></div></div><div class=cssload-half2><div class="cssload-side cssload-s3"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s4"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s6"></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: "команда" это statement ([`single_input` или только `small_stmt`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)) в Питоне?

Comment: @jfs, даже не знаю как грамотно сформулировать

Comment: можно одним выражением ограничиться (то что внутрь `lambda` можно поместить (`test`), запретив сами `lambda`). Или традиционное условие: наименьшее кол-во байт (исходный код в utf-8) выигрывает.

Comment: Входные данные считаются? И в каком виде они? `input()` - конструкция питона, в других языка её нет.

Comment: Мне кажется, в си-подобных языках это не решаемо, т.к. нужно как минимум объявить переменную, а значит разделитель быть обязан.

Comment: Что это за странная таблица результатов? Вроде и с моего сайта... но не та. И к тому же не работает.

Comment: В общем, заменил вам таблицу на рабочую.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, спасибо!

Comment: @PavelMayorov сейчас таблица не работает, ошибка там.

Comment: @PavelMayorov кстати, в JS нет какой-нибудь директивы include, чтобы подключить код непосредственно с гитхаба по raw-ссылке?

Comment: @NickVolynkin какая ошибка-то? У меня работает...

Comment: @PavelMayorov хм, сейчас и у меня работает. Какая была ошибка — не понял, просто `Error: Error...`.

Answer (score 12):

## Python 2, 12 байт

```py
n/60%24,n%60
```

Одно выражение, для заданного числа минут `n` возвращает кортеж `(часы, минуты)`. Пример:

```py
>>> n = 123400
>>> n/60%24,n%60
(16, 40)
```

Два нужных числа присутствуют в выводе. Для проверки:

```py
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> str(timedelta(minutes=n))
'85 days, 16:40:00'
```

Видно, что `16:40` это правильный результат.

Если *`n` только раз можно использовать*, то `divmod(n%1440,60)`(17 байт). Чтобы *напечатать без REPL*, можно `print`  добавить. Если *ввод не в `n`*, а в stdin, то чтобы прочитать: `input()` вместо `n` подставить:

### Python 2, 29 байт

```py
print divmod(input()%1440,60)
```

Выводит: `(16, 40)` для `123400` ввода. Чтобы напечатать *только* числа:

### Python 3, 36 байт

```py
print(*divmod(int(input())%1440,60))
```

Вывод `16 40`.

Так как стрелки по кругу ходят, то задача идеально для деления по модулю подходит:

- `n % 60` - находит позицию минутной стрелки (минуты в последнем часе)
- `n // 60` - минуты в часы превращает, а `% 24` затем находит позицию часовой стрелки (часы в последних сутках)
- `n % 1440` до последних суток обрезает: `1440 == (24 * 60)`
- `divmod(m, 60)` для целых чисел совмещает `m // 60, m % 60`:

  ```py
    hours, minutes = divmod(m, 60)  # == (m // 60, m % 60)
  ```

Comment: мда, `print(*divmod(int(input())%1440,60))` - трудно будет это на Python 3 "переплюнуть"

Comment: ">>> n=3
>>> n/60%24,n%60
(0, 3)" на каких часах можно увидеть подобное? Очевидно, должно быть что-то такое "00:03", ну или на худой конец "00 03", но не сырое "(0, 3)"

Comment: @edem: читаем вопрос: *"Программа должна вывести два числа: количество часов (от 0 до 23) и количество минут (от 0 до 59)"* Посмотрите, хотя бы что решение автора вопроса возвращает. Если не согласны, не понимаете вопроса, то у автора уточнение спросите.

Comment: Тюю, точно, Вы правы, тогда +1.

Comment: @jfs, добавил в вопрос

Comment: Разве не `n//60%24,n%60` (`//` вместо `/`)?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Подумайте чем `/` в Питоне 2 и 3 отличаются (посмотрите на явные версии в ответе).

Comment: Хм, действительно, я же на третьем проверял. )

Answer (score 11):

## Python 3, 43 <s>52</s> <s>60</s>  символов

Моё решение:

43 символа:

```
print('%s %s'%divmod(int(input())%1440,60))
```

52 символа:

```
print('{} {}'.format(*divmod(int(input())%1440,60)))
```

Краткое пояснение:

Функция [divmod(a, b)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) возвращает в качестве результата два значения (кортеж) - результат целочисленного деления `a` на `b` (`a // b`) и остаток от деления `a` на `b` (`a % b`):

```
In [2]: divmod(65, 60)
Out[2]: (1, 5)

In [3]: divmod(1441%1440, 60)
Out[3]: (0, 1)
```

Comment: В гольфе принято: 1) Давать пояснения **как** работает конкурсное решение и 2) Ну... ранжировать результаты нужно, наверное.

Comment: @Other ну ранжирование по числу символов наверное, нет? И наверное зря вы метку питона  убрали, тут вопрос станет что такое одна команда в С++ через запятую например.

Comment: Традиционно мера измерения назначается автором. Как и любые ограничения.

Comment: Воу, а про divmod я не знал)

Comment: Раз это гольф, язык не должен иметь значение, если его не исключили в условиях. Так что...

Comment: @pavel, я новичек в соревнованиях, поэтому даже не знаю как подойти к ранжированию... Наверное краткость и эффективность...

Comment: @MaxU эффективность не померяешь - значит краткость. Но тут проблема - что такое одна команда распишите, с учётом того что стоит метка "любой язык".

Comment: @pavel, спасибо!

Comment: @Other, пардон, я отлучался и не успел пояснение написать. Сейчас добавил...

Comment: можно так: `print(*divmod(int(input())%1440,60))`

Comment: @Danis, да, хорошая идея, вот только этот вариант уже был [оформлен как ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620586/211923) почти 4 года назад ;)

Comment: ой опоздал. пойду возьму свой машину времени и вернусь в 2017

Answer (score 9):

## Bash, 24 символа

(не знаю, насколько это соответствует тегу [любой-язык](/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba), но пусть будет)

```
date -d"0+$n min" +%H:%M
```

Проверка:

```
$ for n in 3 150 1441 444 180 1439 1440 2000 3456 5678 9876
> do
> date -d"0+$n min" +%H:%M
> done
00:03
02:30
00:01
07:24
03:00
23:59
00:00
09:20
09:36
22:38
20:36
```

Comment: Нормально, соответствует. Код-гольф, он же [tag:соревнование], подразумевает использование любого языка, если ограничения не указаны явно.

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 25 символов

```
echo gmdate('H:i',$n*60);
```

[Песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9778f194a463cd9c783d505b57eb20ceab257440)

Comment: А если ещё и `echo` заменить на `=`, то и ещё меньше ))))

Comment: @jfs, значит нужно добавить еще 3 символа.

Answer (score 6):

### C#, 24 с костылями и  ̶5̶1̶   42 символа если правильно

Можно дать прямой доступ к классу Console программе:

```
using static System.Console;
```

и сразу на экран в нужном вам формате времени **(51 символ)**

```
Write(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(n).ToString("hh\\:mm"));
```

А если дать доступ еще и к TimeSpan через using то можно укоротить еще на 9 символов **(42 символа)**:

```
Write(FromMinutes(n).ToString("hh\\:mm"));
```

ВАЖНО: Код сам скажет что он делает. Даже, человеку, который далек от программирования.

---

Более коротко но через зад **(24 символа)**:

```
Write(n/60%24+":"+n%60);
```

Код плохочитаем. Даже, бывалому программисту прийдется думать некоторое время что бы понять что сдесь просходит.

---

Вывод: **Это прекрасный пример показывающий что в программировании "короче" далеко не всегда значит "лучше".**

Comment: "А в Ruby и Swift нету разделительных команд" -- в Ruby всё есть, вы что. И запяточие, и работающий обычно вместо него символ перевода строки (о чём знают не все и [изредка попадают в интересные ситуации](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34071572/2076787)).

Comment: хм, ну да, тыправ. Каретка.... Ну в свифте точно не так)

Comment: И в свифте тоже так же :) Там тоже "каретка" работает вместо запяточия большую часть времени.

Comment: Вспомнил как лажал код когда переводил строку не в том месте.. Ты абсолютно прав! Спасибо за правку.

Comment: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(n) - полноценный вариант, он печатает на консоль при запуске из interactive (варианты на руби и питоне тоже на interactive рассчитаны). Так что 23 символа всего.

Comment: не знал, спасибо. Но не 23 ибо еще нужно переводить в конкретный вид -- часы/минуты. если сделать туСтринг -- все равно выведет на экран? А то сомневаюсь что-то. А проверять влом)

Comment: не могли бы вы пример показать с интерактивной сессией? Будет ли он работать без `using static System.Console;`? Если нет, то следует в размере учесть. Не могли бы вы пример показать полной программы и как запустить для людей незнакомых с C#?

Comment: В оригинальном вопросе не было ничего про то что это только для скриптовых языков и интерактивных сессий. Я с интерактивными сессиями никогда не работал в шарпе и ничего по этому поводу сказать не могу. В консольной апликухе -- просто достаточно скопировать 2 строки в нужные места с чем любой малоопытный программист разберется точно, ведь там все очень интуитивно :) using - к другим юзингам, рабочий код -- в единственный метод который будет создан автоматически. Запустить -- нажать кнопочку "плей" в вижуалке :)

Comment: @Andrew: <- используйте \@ если хотите, чтобы мне оповещения приходили. 1- В вопросе явно написано: *"Программа должна вывести два числа"* . Если ваш код не выводит числа, значит ответ неверный. В [моём ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/620586/23044) в примере с Питоном, выводом REPL занимается (например, в командной строке `python` запустить). Также приведены варианты без REPL (тогда код можно в файл положить и запустить как `python программа.py` и будет вывод получен). Если в C# нет стандартного REPL по умолчанию, то следует привести полную программу, которая вывод производит.

Comment: @jfs, она выводит числа в консоль :) И раз уж топикстартера этот ответ удовлетворил, то почему ставишь минус именно ты? Почему ты считаешь что ты значешь лучше что имел ввиду топикстартер? :)

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 15 символов

```
Time.gm(0)+n*60
```

- исправлен баг с DST по наводке от [jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs) (`new`->`utc`)
- 1 символ срезан, тоже по наводке от [jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs) (`utc`->`gm`)

*Потому что если мы хотим показать **время**, почему бы не воспользоваться классом, который как раз за время и отвечает?*

Используется две вещи, хак и не очень хак:

- **Хак:** `Time.gm(0)` это вызов конструктора `Time` с нулевым годом в таймзоне GMT (чтобы избежать спецэффектов летнего/зимнего времени или DST). Для неуказанных составляющих берутся значения по умолчанию: для часов и минут это нули. Совсем без аргументов же нельзя, т. к. без них будет объект *текущего* времени.
- **Не очень хак:** к объекту класса `Time` можно прибавить число, и оно будет воспринято, как число секунд, посему его надо домножить на 60.

Сессия из `irb` с демонстрацией:

```
$ irb
2.3.1 :001 > n = 123400
 => 123400
2.3.1 :002 > Time.gm(0)+n*60
 => 0000-03-26 16:40:00 +0300
```

Comment: @jfs отличная находка! Пофиксил, счёт прежний, описание поправлю чуть позже.

Comment: Вы можете символ сэкономить: `Time.gm(0)+1060354206*60` -> `02:06`

Comment: @jfs вкрутил, спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

## Java, 37 с костылями и 54 символов, если правильно

Если добавить статический импорт

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.time.LocalTime.MIDNIGHT;
```

чтобы не писать название класса, то можно писать так:

`out.println(MIDNIGHT.plusMinutes(n));`

Полный ответ в 54 символа

```
System.out.println(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.plusMinutes(n));
```

Также можно в 90 символов

```
System.out.println(DateTime.now().withTimeAtStartOfDay().plusMinutes(n).toString("HH:mm"));
```

Answer (score 4):

## C/С++, 29 символов

```
void f(int n){ printf("%d %d",n/60%24,n%60); }
                                           ^
```

Без этой точки с запятой ни в C, ни в C++ просто невозможно. Грамматика не позволит.

Но можно просто одной инструкцией вывода (формально проходит):

```
printf("%d %d",n/60%24,n%60);
```

Comment: А ввод где? Я уже пытался подобное запостить (но со вводом), однако удалил (вам должно быть видно).

Comment: А нам не сказано, что его надо считать. Нам сказано - дословно - **Дано число `n`**. Т.е. переменная уже есть, объявлена, значение присвоено. Решением можно было бы даже считать `printf("%d %d",n/60%24,n%60)`...

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите заголовок в формате, в котором его способна понять таблица результатов :)

Comment: Написано только **"Для составления таблицы просьба правильно оформлять заголовок ответа."**, а как именно - не написано...

Comment: судя [по коду: `/<h[12]>\s*?([^<,]+),\s*?(\d+)/`](https://mayorovp.github.io/codegolf/table-8c505e68f1349e4c69e7.js), достаточно заголовок первого-второго уровня (`#`,`##`) вида: `<Язык>, <число>`

Comment: А кстати, скажите, а там что-то видно? В таблице? А то я вижу вот это: http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0129/3e/8198d170c393173ba3cd3ea0d993f13e.jpg или, если нажать, вот это: http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0129/ca/86e9de5e8a5a4cd6d6231160b38759ca.jpg Так и должно быть? При попытке "выполнить код" ругается NoScript, если его отключить - сообщение об ошибке (начинается с *"message": "ReferenceError: execute is not defined",*)...

Comment: @Harry Значит, не до конца выключили. Функция execute лежит на другом домене, возможно дело в этом.

Answer (score 4):

## JS, 38 символов

Функция:

```
m=>console.log(`${m/60%24|0}:${m%60}`)
```

Пример вывода:

```js
(m=>console.log(`${m/60%24|0}:${m%60}`))(5) // 0:5
```

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, 43 символа (для усложнённой версии задачи)

В текущем виде задача представляет собой обычный вывод результата деления чисел по модулю, и различия для языков программирования при решении оной, лишь в способе вывода этих самых результатов, не более. Сам же способ вычисления относительно стандартен, как можно заметить в большинстве ответов: `$n/60%24` для часов и для минут `$n%60`.

В свете вышесказанного привожу решение для усложнённой версии данной задачи, как если бы вывод программы был идентичен **реальным** электронным часам, например: "00:13", "23:48" и т.д.

```
((($m/60%24).':'.$m%60)=~s/(\b\d\b)/0$1/gr)
```

Проверка:

```
print((($_/60%24).':'.$_%60)=~s/(\b\d\b)/0$1/gr)
    for (3, 150, 1441, 444, 180, 1439, 1440, 2000, 3456, 5678, 9876);

00:03
02:30
00:01
07:24
03:00
23:59
00:00
09:20
09:36
22:38
20:36
```

#### Вариант без нуля для часов, 45 символов

```
((($m/60%24).':'.$m%60)=~s/:(\b\d\b)/:0$1/gr)
```

Проверка:

```
perl -E 'say((($_/60%24).":".$_%60)=~s/:(\b\d\b)/:0$1/gr) for (3, 150, 1441, 444, 180, 1439, 1440, 2000, 3456, 5678, 9876)'

0:03
2:30
0:01
7:24
3:00
23:59
0:00
9:20
9:36
22:38
20:36
```

Comment: 1- Покажите как запустить код (какие флаги указать). 2- **реальные** электронные часы [другие цифры используют](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_clock#/media/File:Digital_clock_changing_numbers.jpg). К примеру: `watch -n1 "date +%T | figlet -k -f clr4x6"`

Comment: @jfs добавил...

Comment: Не совсем понял зачем такие сложности, если есть `*printf`, и короче: `sprintf'%02d:%02d',$m/60%24,$m%60` - 32 байта (получаем строку) или `printf'%02d:%02d',$m/60%24,$m%60` (сразу выводим)

Comment: @PinkTux не хотел использовать возможности форматирования.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 23 символа

```
echo$n/60%24,':',$n%60;
```

P.S. Да, можно писать без пробела -> [песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5379851051c9a4d0bb09e6b081dd0696f4cd2019)

P.P.S. Формулу стащил с других ответов :Р

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 56  символов

Я хоть и слаб еще в питоне, но свой нос тоже хочу всунуть:

```
n=int(input()); ch=(n//60); min=(n-ch*60); print(ch,min)
```

Пусть даже не одной командой, но для новичков пойдет, чтобы разобраться о чем идет речь.

Comment: Но вы же сами в своём вопросе писали, что это решение неправильное

Comment: Это не одна команда.

Comment: @Other: в Питоне это одна команда (`single_input`)

Comment: "без использования точки с запятой (или других разделителей команд)"

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 49 символов

`[DateTime]::Today.addminutes(1).ToString("HH:mm")`

`[DateTime]::Today` - возвращает нам время в 00:00
`addminutes()` - добавляет ко времени минуты
`ToString("HH:mm")` - вывод в формате , можно еще `ToShortTimeString()`

```
PS C:\> @(3, 150, 1441, 444, 180, 1439, 1440, 2000, 3456, 5678, 9876) | foreach{[DateTime]::Today.addminutes($_).ToString("HH:mm")}
00:03
02:30
00:01
07:24
03:00
23:59
00:00
09:20
09:36
22:38
20:36
```