# Задача о переводе минут в часы (Электронные часы) (python)

Tags: python, время

В тренажере по Python столкнулся с задачей "Электронные часы":

> Дано число n. С начала суток прошло n минут. Определите, сколько часов
> и минут будут показывать электронные часы в этот момент. Программа
> должна вывести два числа: количество часов (от 0 до 23) и количество
> минут (от 0 до 59). Учтите, что число n может быть больше, чем
> количество минут в сутках.

Я решил ее таким образом и она прошла все тесты:

```
n = int(input())
hours = n // 60 % 24 
minutes = n % 60
print(hours, minutes)
```

Но практически везде в интернете (я посмотрел много источников), эталонным считается чуть более длинное решение:

```
n = int(input())
hours = n % (60 * 24) // 60
minutes = n % 60
print(hours, minutes)
```

Почему мое решение, судя по всему, является менее оптимальным?

Comment: Очень странно. Ваше решение более понятно и "оптимально", если вообще есть смысл говорить о преимуществе в оптимальности в одну операцию. Единственное, почему второе может быть жизнеспособно - если сразу отбросить лишние сутки модулем: `n = int(input()) % (24 * 60); h, m = n // 60, n % 60`

Comment: заменить `(60 * 24)` на 1440 и количество операций в обоих решениях будет одинаковым, то есть разницы никакой. А чуть покороче можно так: `n = int(input())%1440 ; print(*divmod(n,60))`

Comment: [вот вам в академических целях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/620564/211923) ;)